# How to prevent back button from dissapearing?

Tags: swift, canvas, back

I am creating a doodle page with an "X" as the close/dismiss button.
I also have a "clear" button to remove the doodles that have been made.

My issue is that when I press clear, even the X button disappears, how do I prevent this from happening?

This is my current app.

[image]

This is my Doodle class which allows me to draw on the view.

```
import UIKit

class DoodleView: UIView {

    var lineColor:UIColor!
    var lineWidth:CGFloat!
    var path:UIBezierPath!
    var touchPoint:CGPoint!
    var startingPoint:CGPoint!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

        lineColor = UIColor.white
        lineWidth = 10
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startingPoint = touch?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self)

        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        startingPoint = touchPoint

        drawShapeLayer()
    }

    func drawShapeLayer() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func clearCanvas() {
        path.removeAllPoints()
        self.layer.sublayers = nil
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This is the class controlling the view controller.

```
import UIKit

class DoodlePageViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var doodleView: DoodleView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func clearDoodle(_ sender: Any) {
        doodleView.clearCanvas()
    }


    @IBAction func CloseDoodlePage(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: The most curious part of it - where do you create “X” and “Clear” buttons?

Comment: Does “Clear” button disappear after clicking on it?

Comment: The button were both made using storyboard. And no, only the X button and the doodle disappear. The clear button doesn’t go away

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing the storyboard, but maybe you have added the close button to the DoodleView by mistake?

Comment: Make sure you clear button is in the super view but on top of the doodle view.

Comment: YES. Thanks, both of you. It was just that simple. The button was inside the view and shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 0):

Without really seeing how you declared the buttons, I can only guess that when you call the function `clearCanvas()`, the X button is part of the sublayer in doodle view since you are setting `self.layer.sublayers = nil` hence making it also dissapear.

Make sure that the X button is on top of the doodle view when you create it.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I have done and it has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing all the subviews out of your view when you call `self.layer.sublayers = nil`

you either need to re-add the 'x' view back into the hierarchy. I am assuming using your function drawShapeLayer() is the 'x' ??

so it would be

```
func clearCanvas() {
    path.removeAllPoints()
    self.layer.sublayers = nil

    drawShapeLayer()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: drawShapeLayer( ) is for the user to be able to doodle. I wouldn’t be able to use the code you’ve written as I have created my X button using storyboard, not using swift code.

Comment: @HasnaineShafiq then connect that x button in storyboard to the view controller and re-add it where drawshapelayer() is

Comment: @HasnaineShafiq to be more clear. create an IBOutlet from the button in the story board to your view controller. THen where you clear your canvas with clearCanvas() replace drawShapeLayer() with self.addSubviews(xbutton)